# Javascript echo window.location

Tags: javascript, string, window.location

```
window.location = 'http://...';
```

now I want to assign this location path to a variable, as a normal text string.
I want to achieve:

```
var Path = 'http://...';
```

i tried to use:

```
var Path = window.location;
```

but I get, as this var value:

```
function Path() { [native code] }
```

while I want to have the location text string as its value..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `window.location` is an object, its `href` property returns the entire URL.

See here for a reference on the `location` object (`location`'s other properties & functions can be useful): http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: It should be noted that w3schools is not the best source. For information why, see http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't know that. I updated the ref link to point to MDC.

Answer (score 7):

You want `location.href`. The `location` object is rather more complicated than a simple string.

Answer (score 4):

This should work (though I didn't test):

```
var path = window.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var Path = window.location.toString();
```